# SparkR cannot access to file in workers

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

This question is basically the same as [this one](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/SparkContext-addFile-and-FileNotFoundException-td3844.html) (but in R).

I am developing an R package that uses SparkR. I have created some unit tests (several .R files) in PkgName/inst/tests/testthat using the `testthat` package. For one of the tests I need to read an external data file, and since it is small and is only used in the tests, I read that it can be placed just in the same folder of the tests.

When I deploy this with Maven in a standalone Spark cluster, using "local[*]" as master, it works. However, if I try using a "remote" Spark cluster (via docker -the image has java, Spark 1.5.2 and R- where I create a master in,e.g `http://172.17.0.1` and then a worker that is successfully linked to that master), then it does not work. It complains that the data file cannot be found, because it seems to look for it using an absolute path that is valid only in my local pc but not in the workers. The same happens if I use only the filename (without preceding path).

I have also tried delivering the file to the workers with the --file argument to spark-submit, and the file is successfully delivered (apparently it is placed in `http://192.168.0.160:44977/files/myfile.dat` although the port changes with every execution). If I try to retrieve the file's location using SparkFiles.get, I get a path (that has some random number in one of the intermediate folders) but apparently, it still refers to a path in my local machine. If I try to read the file using the path I've retrieved, it throws the same error (file not found).

I have set the environment variables like this:

```
SPARK_PACKAGES = "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0"
SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS = " --jars /path/to/extra/jars --files /local/path/to/mydata.dat sparkr-shell"
SPARK_MASTER_IP = "spark://172.17.0.1:7077"
```

The INFO messages say:

`INFO Utils: Copying /local/path/to/mydata.dat to /tmp/spark-c86739c6-2c73-468f-8326-f3d03f5abd6b/userFiles-e1e77e47-2689-4882-b60f-327cf99fe5e0/mydata.dat
INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/local/path/to/mydata.dat at http://192.168.0.160:47110/files/mydata.dat with timestamp 1458995156845`

This port changes from one run to another. From within R, I have tried:

`fullpath <- SparkR:::callJStatic("org.apache.spark.SparkFiles", "get", "mydata.dat")`

(here I use `callJStatic` only for debugging purposes) and I get
`/tmp/spark-c86739c6-2c73-468f-8326-f3d03f5abd6b/userFiles-e1e77e47-2689-4882-b60f-327cf99fe5e0/ratings.dat`

but when I try to read from `fullpath` in R, I get fileNotFound exception, probably because `fullpath` is not the location in the workers. When I try to read simply from "mydata.dat" (without a full path) I get the same error, because R is still trying to read from my local path where my project is placed (just appends "mydata.dat" to that local path).

I have also tried delivering my R package to the workers (not sure if this may help or not), following the correct packaging conventions (a JAR file with a strict structure and so on). I get no errors (seems the JAR file with my R package can be installed in the workers) but with no luck.

Could you help me please? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I think I was wrong and I don't need to access the file in the workers but *just in the driver*, because the access is not part of a distributed operation (just calling `SparkR::read.df`). Anyway it does not work. But surprisingly, if I pass the file with `--files` and I read it with `read.table` (not from SparkR but the basic R utils) passing the full path returned by SparkFiles.get, it works (although this is useless to me). Btw I'm using SparkR version 1.5.2.

Comment: It would be easier if you show us your code.

Comment: I do not have much code here, it is rather a matter of how things should be connected and configured. Anyway I have copied some stuff to make my point clearer.